# Napoleon's theorem with quadrilaterals

Tags: geometry

Take a quadrilateral and draw squares on its edges facing outward. Prove that the quadrilateral whose vertices are the centres of these squares is a square if and only if the original quadrilateral is a parallelogram.

It feels like it should have a proof similar to that of [Napoleon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Napoleon's_theorem) but I can't figure it out.

Could you help me?

Comment: Napoleon-Barlotti theorem: *The centres of regular $n$-gons constructed over the sides of an $n$-gon $P$ form a regular $n$-gon if and only if $P$ is an afﬁne image of a regular $n$-gon.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the classical van Aubel theorem (1878)

This problem is presented on many sites like

(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Aubel's_theorem)

and proved in http://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Geometry/SqOnQuadri.shtml#Discussion

Mentionned also in

http://scimath.unl.edu/MIM/files/MATExamFiles/LaFleur%20Expository_FINAL.pdf

http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Perp/QuadSq.html

etc...